# Cant retrieve EventRelayConfig metadata in VSCode

Tags: visualstudiocode, aws

im  playing around with the rather new event relay feature that integrates salesforce into AWS. The feature itself works fine but I stumbled upon the metadata page in the salesforce docs ( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.244.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_eventrelayconfig.htm) and now Id like to actually have the event relay in our git. I cant seem to retrieve the metadata whatsoever though.

The error I get is

> Missing metadata type definition in registry for id 'eventrelayconfig'.
> when trying to retrieve it via package.xml or org browser.

Has anyone worked with this before and managed to actually retrieve the metadata?

Comment: can you paste your package.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‘EventRelayConfig' type is not available in registry using VS code(metadata API), same can be found in metadata [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/58).

Here is the [list](https://github.com/forcedotcom/source-deploy-retrieve/blob/main/src/registry/metadataRegistry.json) of available registries, As a workaround you can use workbench to retrieve and deploy.

Also, we have internal work item ***#W-12157698*** created to add EventRelayConfig to metadata registry in coming releases.